# Python - Apply dictionary to list while leaving other elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list, a, defined as the following:

```
a = ['3', 'A', '+', 'Q', '2', '/', '*']
```

I have a dictionary, d, defined as the following:

```
d = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6' : 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '0': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13}
```

I want to apply the dictionary to the elements of the list that are in the dictionary, including 3, A, Q, and 2, while leaving the operations in the same locations and in the same string format. I've tried to use list comprehension, but that tried to apply it to the operations as well.

My desired output would be as follows:

```
a = [3, 1, '+', 12, 2, '/', '*']
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you listed your desired output

Comment: While there are people providing answers right now, the next time, please provide your own coding attempt when posting a question. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Also, learn about how to put together an [mcve]. Overall, asking for an answer without showing your own effort typically gets a question closed fairly quickly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dict.get` to specify default values if the key is not present in a dictionary:

```
a = ['3', 'A', '+', 'Q', '2', '/', '*']
d = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6' : 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '0': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13}

[d.get(c, c) for c in a] # produces [3, 1, '+', 12, 2, '/', '*']
```

This says, for each character `c` in `a`, lookup the value for that character in `d`, or just return `c` if the character is not present.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will do the substitution at the same time preserving any operators present in the mapping. However, you need to specify all the possible operators in another list,

```
a = ['3', 'A', '+', 'Q', '2', '/', '*']
ops = ['+','/','*','-'] # contains all operators
d = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6' : 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '0': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13}

result = [c if c in ops else d.get(c, c) for c in a]
print(result)
```

The output is,

```
[3, 1, '+', 12, 2, '/', '*']
```

What if the dictionary contains mapping for '+'?,

```
a = ['3', 'A', '+', 'Q', '2', '/', '*']
ops = ['+','/','*','-'] # contains all operators
d = {'+':2,'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6' : 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '0': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13}

result = [c if c in ops else d.get(c, c) for c in a]
print(result)
```

The output still is the same,

```
[3, 1, '+', 12, 2, '/', '*']
```